# Can any one tell where i went wrong in applying CSS

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I applied a `css` for image button as follows

```
<style type="text/css">
    .selected
    {
        padding-left:50px;
        background: transparent url('Images/samplecopy.jpg') ;
        background-repeat: repeat;
    }
</style>
```

`<asp:ImageButton ID="btnYes" CssClass="selected" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/image.jpg" />`

But i am not getting as per required. i would like to cover the whole `image button` with the background image that applied

[image]

I need to hover that black back ground exactly on the image can any one help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the padding, that's what causing the problem.

Use the following code and see if it helps

```
<style type="text/css">
.selected
{
    padding:0px;
    background: transparent url('Images/samplecopy.jpg') ;
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
</style>
```

**UPDATE**

```
clear: both;
padding: 5px;
border: 1px;
background: transparent url('Images/samplecopy.jpg') ;
background-repeat: repeat;
color: #FFF;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 12px;
border-radius:3px;
```

Try these properties in CSS and tell me if it helps.

Comment: But i am unable to apply that back color what i needed

Comment: I would like to show that back color image on that Image button

Comment: I have updated the answer. Try this and let me know, if this is what you want

Comment: Yes if i need that to apply completely on  the image what should i do

Comment: I have updated the code to use your image...hope it can make things work

Comment: Hi i need small help how can i remove that class when i `mouseout` from the button

Comment: You can take help of Psuedo classes and have one normal class and one hover class. For example , use `yourCSS { ... }` for basic display and use `yourCSS:hover { ... }` for mouseover. You can visit this for more info : [Pseudo class](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css_pseudo_classes.asp)